# Rep recalc on all nominees for election

Tags: feature-request, reputation-recalc, nominations, election

I would like to see some public accountability in the form of all election nominees receiving, as part of their self-nomination, a rep-recalc.  It shouldn't impact many, but since the election now appears to be very dependent on reputation, and since the recent opening of other stackexchange sites have shuffled many popular questions off site, it behooves us to hold our future leaders to a high standard.

In the future it would be nice if this were automated, in other words in the process of nomination the rep recalc is performed by the system automatically.

Comment: I recalculate my rep frequently, so that my reputation is never too far off. good idea! +1

Comment: Recalculated rep for User.Id = [2915](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2915/pollyanna) -> old rep = 22759, new rep = 21923

Comment: Recalculated rep for User.Id = [1228](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1228/will) -> old rep = 3831, new rep = 3667

Comment: Recalculated rep for User.Id = [144987](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/144987/studiohack) -> old rep = 1738, new rep = 1738 (lol)

Comment: @Will - 5% is nothing.  Try recalcing my SO account to see if you can do better than a 5% loss.

Comment: Why shouldn't recalc be automated *for everybody* in the future?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder.  I actually gained ~800 points after the manual recalculation.  That's what I get for downvoting spam.

Comment: @Arjan the system does recalc, but I don't know what the algo is for when it decides to take your rep back.

Answer (score 12):

I would support this, but only if all nominees had their rep re-calculated.  I stand to lose ~300 rep (which I don't mind) but I wouldn't want to lose my spot in the primaries to someone with slightly higher rep that hadn't recalculated.